# Foreach loop not looping through checkbox list asp .net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, .net, foreach

I am trying to read a list of values that exist in a SQL database and if the value exists, it needs to check a checkbox in a checkbox list. At the moment, I can read the values of a specific employee but when I try to loop through the checkbox list, it skips it completely. I can add a new data entry by checking items perfectly but it's only reading that is causing issues:

My sample code below is to test whether it even loops through the checkbox list.

```cs
var asd = GetEmployeeSpecificDisabilities(idNum, connString); //returns a list of a specific employees disabilities;

string value = string.Empty;

foreach (ListItem item in disabilityList.Items)
{
    value += item.Selected ? item.Text + "," : "";
```

The below code works perfectly when adding new employee details:

```cs
//create new list object
EmployeeList newEmployee = new EmployeeList();
    
newEmployee.EmployeeNumber = txtEmployeeNumber.Text;
newEmployee.IDNumber = txtIDnumber.Text;
newEmployee.employeeSurname = txtSurname.Text;
newEmployee.employeeName = txtName.Text;
newEmployee.numberOfDependants = Convert.ToInt32(txtNumOfDependants.Text);
newEmployee.Race = lsRaces.SelectedValue;
newEmployee.Gender = lsGender.SelectedValue;
                    
//if employee has a disability
if (disabilityList.Visible == true)
{
    foreach (ListItem x in disabilityList.Items)
    {
        if (x.Selected)
        {
            newEmployee.Disabilityreference_Id = Convert.ToInt32(x.Value);
            newEmployee.CreateNewEmployee(connString, newEmployee);
        }
    }
} 
else
{
    newEmployee.CreateNewEmployee(connString, newEmployee);
}
    
Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
```

Front end code:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="disabilityList" runat="server" style="left: 19px; top: 3px; width: 266px; border:medium; padding:inherit" DataSourceID="Disabilities" DataTextField="DisabilityReference" DataValueField="Id" Visible ="true" CssClass="checkbox checkbox"  Font-Size="Medium">
        </asp:CheckBoxList>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="Disabilities" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:EmployeeDBConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Disabilities]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you need to iterate `GetEmployeeSpecificDisabilities` and compare with `disabilityList` something like that:

```
var employeeDisabilities = GetEmployeeSpecificDisabilities(idNum, connString);
 
foreach(var employeeDisability in employeeDisabilities)
{
    foreach (ListItem item in disabilityList.Items)
    {
        if(item.Value == employeeDisability.Disabilityreference_Id.ToString())
        {
            item.Selected = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for this. I've tried this but the issue is that it doesn't recognise the variable "Item" in this context. It loops 5 times as it should but exists the loop with no changes front end.

Comment: Don't you have any items in `disabilityList`? Where do you initialize this checkbox list?

Comment: I initialize it in the front end code. Unless I'm initializing it incorrectly? But perhaps you can advise?

Comment: It seems okay, so do you have any item in  `disabilityList`?

Comment: I have 5 items in disabilityList and it loops 5 times  but it looks almost as it if it's not getting the element